# Laravel query builder Carbon instance need format()

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, timestamp, php-carbon

I have a query in Laravel made with the query builder, and because of this i can not use the Carbon format() function. What other way can i do it so my timestamp shows up as for example 23 March, 2015. thankyou

Comment: I solved the problem by using date('F d, o', strtotime($topic->created_at))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carbon is a library that can produce similar output to the php date() function.   So you can replace it with the date() function, pass it a format string, I think 'd M, Y' would give you want you want.